# How to update mixed column scheme in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a scheme

```
let AccountSchema = new Schema({
    permission: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed },
    type : {type : Number}
});
```

When I update a document

```
let item = new Account({
    _id : xxxxxxx,
    permission : [{
        '1' : '1',
        '2' : '2'
    }],
    type : 2
});
item.save();
```

But this document just modify type without modify permission. My Scheme have many other column , If I use item.markModified('permission') in case sure update `permission` will be ok, but I don't sure in each case I need update `permission` or not. I mean I will need to full parameter in scheme to update data.. :( . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Schema.Types.Mixed` you have to consider that this is a `schema-less type` meaning that [Mongoose would not automatically keep track](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) of the changes like it would for the `Number` type.

You are responsible to keep those changes monitored and call `markModified` in order to signal to mongoose to update/save the changes.

So something like this should work:

```
let item = new Account({
    permission : [{ a : 1 }],
    type : 2
});
item.save();
```

But any changes after that to objects in the permissions would need to be `markModified`

You can find more details as well as the actual path you have to provide to the [markModified here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified)